# If $\sum\limits^n_{r=1} r f(r) = n(n+1)$ and $f(1)= \dfrac12$, find $f(1000)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

If for $f : \Bbb N \to \Bbb R$,
$$\sum\limits^n_{r=1} r f(r) = n(n+1)$$ 
and $f(1) = \dfrac12$ where $n \ge 2$, find $f(1000)$.

I calculated some terms
$$f(1) = \dfrac12$$
$$2f(2) = 2\cdot 3 - \dfrac 12 = \dfrac {11}2$$

So, $f(1) + 2f(2) = 6$

$$3f(3) = 3\cdot 4 - 6 = 6$$
$$4f(4) = 4\cdot 5 - 6 - 6 = 8$$

Looking at the pattern, I hypothesise that $nf(n) = 2n$ for $n > 2$. I think this can be proved by induction if it is true.

So $f(n) = 2$ for $n > 2$, thus $f(1000) = 2$.

The answer given is $\dfrac 1{2000}$, which is so much different from my answer. I feel very stupid now, all I did is basic arthmetic operations to get my answer. I think I should go back to my brothers class to relearn these things.

How did I go so wrong with my answer ?

Comment: Hint for shorter solutions:
$$2n=n(n+1)-(n-1)n=\sum_{r=1}^nrf(r)-\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}rf(r)=nf(n)\\\implies f(n)=2$$

Comment: I don't understand how $f(1)=\frac12$. Note that$$f(1)=\sum_{r=1}^1rf(r)=1(1+1)=2\ne\frac12$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt $n \ge 2$ for the sum. So you cannot write $1$ as $n$.

Comment: Ah... then it should be $f(n)=2,~n>2$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yes It should be.

Comment: So yeah, either you copied the problem incorrectly or the textbook is wrong.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I did not copy incorrectly. The solution in textbook says $f(n) = \dfrac 1{2n}$.

Comment: :-/ well that's obviously false.$$\sum_{r=1}^nr\frac1{2r}=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac12=\frac n2\ne n(n+1)$$

Comment: No... it should be $n/2$, check a few values?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Sorry confused my self with $n \ge 2$ and $n > 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code I wrote for the function $f$ in Python on [repl.it](https://repl.it/KtRj/0). It outputs the exact same answer you found. Humans can easily mess up with computations but computers rarely do so. They are made for it.

So I totally agree with your answer and this is heavy evidence that the textbook may be wrong.

(I will leave the code below just in case the site goes down or deletes it)

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def f(n):
  if n == 1:
    return 1/2
  else:
    return n + 1 - (1/n) * sum(r * f(r) for r in range(1, n))

print(f(1000))
```